# Failed to fetch post request: React with Node.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, fetch

I need your help. I have a `react` site in the middle of which I have a `node.js` server piece written in express that consists of a `server.js` file.  I'm trying to connect them together to send requests to the server and have them run together. I have no errors in the code, I start the server using the `npm run server` command, the server starts, but when I make a `fetch` post request, I get a `failed to fetch` error. Please tell me where my mistake is, how to connect them together?

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const cors = require('cors');

require('dotenv').config();
const path = require('path');

const app = express();
const port = 8000;
const host = 'localhost';

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});

const transport = {
  service: 'gmail',
  host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
  port: 587,
  auth: {
      user: process.env.EMAIL,
      pass: process.env.PASS
  }
};

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(transport);
transporter.verify((error, success) => {
  if (error) {
    console.error(error);
  } else {
    console.log('Server is ready to take messages');
  }
});

const router = express.Router();

router.post('/send', (req, res, next) => {
try {
    const name = req.body.name;
    const phone = req.body.number;
    const email = req.body.email;
    const message = req.body.message;

    const content = `Name: ${name} \n Phone: ${phone} \n Email: ${email} \n Message: ${message} \n`;
    const mail = {
        from: transport.auth.user,
        to: 'dimasik11chernyak@gmail.com',
        subject: 'New Message',
        text: content
    };
    transporter.sendMail(mail, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            res.json({
                status: 'fail'
            });
        } else {
            res.json({
                status: 'success'
            });
        }
    });
    res.status(200).send(content)
} catch (error) {
    res.status(400).send(error.message);
    console.error(error);
}
});

const http = require("http");
let server = http.createServer(app);
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use('/', router);
server.listen(port,host, () => {
    console.log(`Server is up!`);
});
```

`server.js` is at the first level of the project's react folder.

package.json

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "react-scripts start",
  "startMobile": "react-scripts start --host 192.168.31.149",
  "build": "react-scripts build",
  "test": "react-scripts test",
  "eject": "react-scripts eject",
  "server": "node server.js"
}
```

my request

```
const objectSend = {
        name: inputValues.name,
        email: inputValues.email,
        number: inputValues.number,
        message: inputValues.message
    }

    await fetch(`http://localhost:8000/send`, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(objectSend)
    }).then(res => res.json());
```

Comment: Is there any more information at all about the "failed to fetch" error?  In the browser's debugging tools on the console tab or the network tab?

Comment: It would be helpful to provide the complete error from the client along with any server side logs.

Comment: @David, 
No, I just send the request and I keep getting this error. As the endpoint does not exist, as I did not connect something

Comment: @DaveNewton, Failed to fetch
TypeError: Failed to fetch

Comment: And in the network tab?

Comment: @DaveNewton Just error, with body I send and no response